# Targeting S+(version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent[React-native-nordic]

Tags: react-native, android-pendingintent, android-12, androidsdk31

I'm trying to update BLE firmware OTA but i'm getting issue when i call startDfu through react-native-nordic-dfu

I have added
`implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'`
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'`

i'm not using PendingIntent in my project